# Processing Data in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

What is the "best" approach pass data between multiple steps in an ssis package?

Currently I'm reading / loading all data in one big dataflow task. 
After that, I would like to validate all data in a script task outside of the datafow task where the data gets loaded.

[image]

(the validation can not happen within the dataflow task since I need all calculations that happen withing there to be finished to check weather the data is OK or not)

As far as I know there is no easy "out of the box" way to pass data from one task to another. One approach I tried was storing a recordset in a object variable bot it seems very hacky. Another option would be to store the data in the database but it seems not very clean to me since the data should not leave the memory until all validation is done, right?

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is using multiple steps for something like this a wrong approach?

**EDIT:**

I'm reading out a list of useraccounts containing ID, name, surname, mail and state. The data would look like this:

```
123;John;Malcovic;jm@gmail.com;active
```

The verification will for example check the state of all useraccounts. If more then five rows have a stet "inactive" the whole job should abort.

Since "Read data" task does load data out over two different systems, not just the SQL database, the load needs to be completely finished before the verification can begin.

Comment: My go-to option for this is usually a flat file, but it really depends on what you need to do? What kind of data are you trying to share between tasks and why would you be splitting it up? Can you give us a bit more information? (If it is simply to validate, then why would you not be validating as you go? It seems odd the database would accept 'bad' values in the first place?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah a flat file would be another option but in my oppinion that should not be necessary. There really should be a way where I don't have to leave the "in memory cache" to move data no another step. This looks so complicated fo such an easy task...

Comment: Why do you wanna use a SQL TASK to validate your data? You can do it in a simple SQL statement. Insert Read Data into a temp table. Validate on top of your temp table and pass it through if it meets your requirements

Comment: I dont want to use a SQL Task to validate it. The SQL Task is to read the data. from there I planned to do everything in memory to prevent any pressure on the DB until the data is validated and can be inserted / updated. Assuming this is not a wron approach...

Answer (score 2):

Typically best solution for this is staging tables.

Staging tables are usually all varchar columns in exact form as the input data table. So steps in your case will be:

1. Load all data as is without any validation into staging tables.
2. Apply validation using SQL queries and flag rows in staging tables which should not be imported. Good way will be to have two column like IsGoodToImport (boolean) and ErrorDetails(varchar(max)). Latter will store all data related to validation errors if any
3. lastly load all IsGoodToImport =1 rows from staging table to your actual data table. And then work on the bad rows for reporting back to source or correcting them.

On why Staging tables (i.e. DB) vs SSIS

- you never lose the data from source as they are always in staging tables
- it is very much faster to do in DB ( think raw vs batch wise SSIS in memory operation using .NET libraries )
- SQL server is way better product in handling large data vs SSIS

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The only thing I don't like so much aout this approch is, that we put unnecessary pressure on the DB in my oppinion. Assuming we have 5 million rows we would have to enter everything into the staging table first an then process every row. This is a task the package should haldl "in memory" in my ofinion since we should not stress the DB untill it is really necessary...

Comment: typically DB is better because: 1) you never lose the data from source as they are always in staging tables 2) it is very much faster to do in DB ( think raw vs batch wise SSIS in memory operation using .NET libraries ) 3) SQL server is way better product in handling large data vs SSIS